# Adding custom object to function

Tags: object, javascript

I'm making a mini JavaScript library and I am trying to allow people to add custom functions.

The current syntax is:

```
$$.custom('alert', function(){alert(this._string)});
```

To trigger the alert you would use the following:

```
$$.string("Hi").alert();
```

The issue is that `this._string` is supposed to return the string between `()` (it does for the normal functions) but instead it is returning `undefined`.

This is the code I use for the setup of the `$$` object:

```
var g = function (a) {
        this._string = typeof a == "string" ? a : "undefined"
    },
    NumberPro = function (a) { 
        this._number = typeof a == "number" ? a : "undefined"
    },
    $$ = { 
        string: function (a) {
            return new g(a)
        },
        number: function (a) {
            return new NumberPro(a)
        },
        syntax: { 
            off: function () {
                for (var j in k) {
                    String.prototype[j] = String.prototype[j] || k[j];
                };
                for (var j in l) {
                    Number.prototype[j] = Number.prototype[j] || l[j];
                };
                type = 'prototype';
            },
            on: function () { 
                for (var j in l) {
                    NumberPro.prototype[j] = NumberPro.prototype[j] || l[j]
                }
                for (var j in k) {
                    g.prototype[j] = g.prototype[j] || k[j]
                }
                type = '';
            }
        },
        usePrototype: function (a) { 
            $$.syntax.off();
            a();
            $$.syntax.on();
        },
        custom: function(name, f){
            k[name] = f();
            for (var j in k) {
                    g.prototype[j] = g.prototype[j] || k[j]
                }
                type = '';
        }
    },
    type = '',
    Methods = $$;
```

In the "custom", function...in `k[name] = f()`, the `k` is the object which the rest of the functions are stored in. I run a `for` loop to give each of them the `$$.string` object.

What I want to do is be able to add `this._string` to the function submitted in the custom alert function. I'm thinking this could be possible but I can't seem to get this to work. I hope I gave enough code so I can get a good answer. I though my way should work since in the custom function I'm running the for again to give the added function the `$$` object too so `this._string` should be retrieving the string.

Thanks in advance.